# MUI Chip не стилизуется

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mui

Всем привет. Я использую библиотеку Mui
В [документации](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/chip/#css) написано то есть слот deleteIconFilledColorSecondary.
Но он не работает. Иконка крестика должна быть белой для заполненных Chip, а она всё равно красная, будто это outlined стиль. Пожалуйста помогите решить данную проблему.
Сделал [песочницу](https://codesandbox.io/embed/mui-chip-forked-sjj7zk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) для наглядности

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено! Необходимо обновить пакет @mui/material до версии 5.9.3